# AccessViolation during PInvoke

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, dllimport

I have this dll call:

```
 [DllImport("FreqCntPcIntf.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern Intf_ErrorType FreqCntIntf_Init(
        ref byte InstNo, 
        string InstName, 
        string PortServerName, 
        ulong UartComPort, 
        ulong MaxBlockTime);

enum Intf_ErrorType
{
    ...
}
```

And the C++ declaration is this:

```
FREQCNTINTF_API Intf_ErrorType STDCALL FreqCntIntf_Init(InstanceNoType* InstNo, const char* InstName, const char* PortServerName, rsuint32 UartComPort, rsuint32 MaxBlockTime);
```

where:

```
typedef enum 
{
   ....
}  RSENUM8(Intf_ErrorType);

#define FREQCNTINTF_API __declspec(dllexport)
typedef rsuint8 InstanceNoType;
typedef unsigned char rsuint8;
#define RSENUM32(EnumName)  Enum_##EnumName; typedef rsuint32 EnumName
```

I receive AccessViolation during call. Where should I look to find the bug?

Comment: ulong in C# is 8 byte wide, not 4 bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsuint32` should be expressed as `uint`, which is 4-byte wide, not `ulong`, which in C# is 8 byte long. Also, you might want to make sure, that your strings are marshalled proplery, by specifying CharSet, like this:

```
[DllImport("FreqCntPcIntf.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
```

Comment: Thanks, my fault, I confused long and int. Shame to me :) But anyway that doesn't help - my code is throwing AccessViolationException. I also tried all charset - nothing helps

Comment: Found the problem. Together with what you've pointed I passed one of the strings as null. Seems that they shouldn't be null. Thanks